# why while loop is printing only the first element in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

using System;

```
namespace Loop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] Numbers = new int[3];

            Numbers[0] = 101;
            Numbers[1] = 102;
            Numbers[2] = 103;

            int i = 0;
            while (i < Numbers.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers are: "+ Numbers[i]);
                i++;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qww2I.png)

Comment: `Console.ReadKey();` - just press it

Comment: It waits for user input here Console.ReadKey();

Comment: Well did you press a key after it had printed 101? It works fine for me...

Comment: Put `Console.ReadKey()` after the `while` loop. Simple debugging would tell you that when you hit this statement, console pops up because it needs key input from you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

otherwise it will wait for the user input

Answer (score 1):

Please remove

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Because `Readkey()` method waiting for input. If you debug your program would you realize it is what was wrong

Comment: There's no need to try to @ notify the question asker. They're automatically notified when someone writes an *answer*, which is what you have done.

Comment: thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Loop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] Numbers = new int[3];

            Numbers[0] = 101;
            Numbers[1] = 102;
            Numbers[2] = 103;

            int i = 0;
            while (i < Numbers.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers are: "+ Numbers[i]);
                i++;

            }
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to wait and read console  `Console.ReadKey();`must be outside from while loop

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Console.ReadKey(); this be should be out of the loop.

Comment: This appears to duplicate existing answers. You should upvote those answer(s) that you believe are helpful to you and *accept* one of them. Unless you're claiming that this answer is somehow different to the other answers.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answer's my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)